# Question on an equation involving sum of a function over divisors.

Tags: summation, divisor-sum

I have a simple question regarding a particular form of a sum and I was hoping someone could provide some insights or guidance.

I was wondering if there was any other way to express the following sum by using mobius inversion or some other form of transformation:

$$\sum_{d|n} \frac{{n/d}}{\varphi\left(n/d\right)}$$

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that $d \le n$ or $d | n$? If $d | n$ then it would be multiplicative.

Comment: $d|n$, i have corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{d|n} \frac{{n/d}}{\varphi(n/d)}\\
&=\sum_{d|n} \frac{d}{\varphi(d)}\\
s(p)
&=\sum_{d|p} \frac{d}{\varphi(d)}\\
&=\frac{{1}}{\varphi\left(1\right)}+\frac{p}{\varphi(p)}\\
&=1+\frac{p}{p-1}\\
&=\frac{2p-1}{p-1}\\
s(p^m)
&=\sum_{d|p^m} \frac{d}{\varphi(d)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{p^k}{\varphi(p^k)}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{p^k}{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{p}{(p-1)}\\
&=1+\frac{mp}{(p-1)}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)p-1}{(p-1)}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)(p-1)+m+1-1}{(p-1)}\\
&=m+1+\frac{m}{(p-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$d$ and $\varphi(d)$
are multiplicative,
so is
$\frac{d}{\varphi(d)}$
and so,
if
$n=\prod p_i^{m_i}$
then
$s(n)=\prod s(p_i^{m_i})$.

So,
if $n=\prod p_i^{m_i}$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=s(\prod p_i^{m_i})\\
&=\prod (m_i+1+\frac{m_i}{(p-1)}))\\
\end{array}
$